Why my react query hook is not updating the data using the OnSuccess method
Im using react query to interact with the backend, work just fine but when i use mutation i got some problems:
1 - how to get all the keys and data related to that key
2 - how to update data optimistically, i just copy the example in the doc but it doesnt work.
3 - only update if i invalidate the Query and refetch and i want to be anle to do it using onSuccess
i go this
//query
export const useUsers = (clientId, businessId) => {
    return useQuery ({
        queryKey: ['users'],
        queryFn: () => getUsers(clientId, businessId),
    })
}
//mutation
export const useDisableUser = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    return useMutation ({
        mutationFn: (clientId) => disableUser(clientId),
        
        onSuccess: (response, variables, context) => {
            const userId = variables;

            return queryClient.setQueryData(['users'], (previous) => {
                return previous.map((user) => {
                    if(user.user_id === userId) {
                        return {...user, active: false};
                    } else {
                        return user;
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        
        // onSettled: async (_, error) => {
        //  if(error){
        //      console.log (error)
        //  } else {
        //      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey: ['users']})
        //  }
        // },
        
        onError: (error, variables, context) => {
            debugger
        }
    })
}

